# How to use ConfigMap in AKS and Azure Configuration in C#

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, configmap, azure-app-configuration

In our application we are using Azure App Configuration for all the configration and we are deploying it to AKS. I am using Config map just to keep the Azure App configuration endpoint and application is able to read that but its not able to read values from the Azure App Configuration(though its able to connect). is there a place I should tell application to use one or other ? currently I am loading it like this.

```
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
{
    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DockerEnv") == "Docker")
    {
        config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        // setting configmap
        .AddJsonFile("ConfigiurationFilePath", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    }
});

 builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(option =>
    option.Connect(new Uri(ConfigEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential()));
```

application is able to read the config emdpoint and connect to Azure App Configuration. but when I try to read the value through Iconfiguration value in the configmap is returned successfully but value in the app configuration is not returning.

```
_configuration.GetValue<string>("TestConfig")
```

should I use different ways to read from different config or I should use some sort of configuration builder to read values from both ?

Comment: You are facing the issue locally or in the deployed App?

Comment: in the deployed application. when I portforward and validate, I couldnt get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by moving all the config to one single place. Here is the code.

```
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DockerEnv") == "Docker")
    {
        config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        // setting configmap
        .AddJsonFile("ConfigiurationFilePath", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(option =>
        {
        option.Connect(new Uri("enpoint"), new DefaultAzureCredential()));

    }
});
```